# use any viewController in navigationController stack to present viewController cause offset to be zero

Tags: modal-dialog, presentviewcontroller

when I use a viewController which is in navigationController stack to present viewController like this:

```
[fooViewController presentViewController:barViewController animated:YES completion:nil]
```

it will be working, but when barViewController has been dismissed and it back to fooViewController, 
fooViewController.view will be shown on top to the screen , not under the navigation bar, why ? How can I fix it?

still I am trying to :

```
[fooViewController.navigationController presentViewController:barViewController animated:YES completion:nil]
```

it's not working, why ?

which kind of viewControllers I can use to presentViewController?